# Launching powershell script from cmd without using double quotes (")

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

I need to launch a powershell command from cmd without using double quotes `"`

My current command:

```
powershell.exe -noexit Start-BitsTransfer -Source 'download link' -Destination 'C:\test.txt'
```

The error:

```
The string is missing the terminator: '.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString
```

The reason I cannot use double quotes is because I'm using the `post-install-command=` parameter from `vboxmanage` which already uses double quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- It's **best to enclose everything starting with `Start-BitsTransfer` in (escaped) `"..."`**, i.e., to pass a *single*, double-quoted string to the (positionally implied) `-Command` parameter of [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe)), which prevents `cmd.exe` from interpreting the string's content (except, potentially, `cmd.exe`-format environment-variable references such as `%OS%`).

  - Without `"..."`, as in your case, a `&` *outside* a `"..."` string is then interpreted as a `cmd.exe` *metacharacter* (statement separator), and the call *breaks* (`'...'` strings are only recognized by PowerShell, not by `cmd.exe`).
  - While you could `^`-escape all cmd.exe metacharacters *individually*, enclosing the entire `-Command` argument in `"..."` is the simpler solution. (Also, even though it is rarely a problem in practice, whitespace normalization occurs in the absence of `"..."` enclosure, i.e. runs of *multiple* spaces are folded into one space per run).
- Since **your entire `powershell.exe` command is itself embedded in a `"..."` string passed as part of an option to `vboxmanage`**, you must ***escape* the `"` chars**. that are part of the `powershell.exe` call, namely **as `\"`**.

Therefore, in the context of your `vboxmanage` call, use something like the following - note the outer `"..."` and embedded inner `\"...\"`:

```
vboxmanage ... post-install-command="powershell.exe -noexit \"Start-BitsTransfer -Source 'download link' -Destination 'C:\test.txt'\""
```